# Jenkins Selenium Click Element Fails

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I have Jenkins configured as a Windows Service and it executes the selenium Job.
By manually running the test through command prompt , works fine in identifying the element , but the same fails when executed through Jenkins. Any pointers will help and here is a code snippet used .

```
selenium.click(xpath);
```

Comment: What user does the Jenkins service runs as?

Comment: It runs under Local System also have tried to run in the User Account which is currently logged in. Both fails

Comment: Since you are running UI tests, you need a desktop. Services don't have desktop access. Search stackoverflow for UI testing.